# What does this .NET Framework Initialization error mean and how do I avoid it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Here's the error:

> To run this application, you first must install one of the following
>   versions of the .NET Framework: v4.0.30319.

My question is, how do I develop a C# program in VS 2010 Professional that I can give to any of my friends without them running into the above error?  I just want them to be able to run what I've created without having to install a single thing.  Generally, speaking we are all on 64-bit Windows 7.

I thought creating a C# program in VS 2010 would allow me to give it to anyone running Windows 7 and they can run it right away without having to do extra work.

Comment: Make them install the .net framework. There is no getting around it.

Comment: Tell them to upgrade to SP1 or downgrade your program to .NET 3.5.

Comment: Regarding Windows 7, you can be 99% certain that it has .NET framework 4.0 installed. While .NET4.0 is not part of the Win7 installation routine, it is part of the standard Windows Update process. Unless your friends love to tinker around with Windows Update, you can assume they have .NET 4.0 already. Otherwise, stick with .NET3.5 which is part of Windows 7 installation routine.

Comment: @elgonzo If what you're saying is true, are you then saying that something in my program requires .NET Framework v4.0.3 instead of the 4.0 framework that is supposedly 99% already installed?

Comment: @Phan, if .NET 4.0 is installed on a Win7 machine, the Windows Update process will also apply patches such as 4.0.30319 -- unless you tinker with the Windows Update process (or switch it off, which generally is not recommendable). Again, if you can you assume that a Win7 machine is properly updated, go ahead with whatever .NET4.0 patch version your program likes. However, if you cannot assume that and do not want to tell your users to install .NET4.0, stick with .NET3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe windows 7 ships with NET framework 3.5. So you have to build your applications with 3.5 as the target so that the users can run without installing anything. But if you happen to use .net 4 libraries in your exe and if you cannot retarget, then tough luck for users.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a beginner question and will reveal the extent of my ignorance but here goes: How do I know if I'm using any .net 4 libraries?  I just made a simple Windows FOrms Application, and when I look at my Using statements it looks like this (using.System.ABC): .Linq, .Text, .IO, .Data.OleDb, .Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: to find out quick, you can change the target framework in your project settings to 3.5 and if you compile and dont have any errors, you are fine.

Comment: Oh no!  I get the error The referenced component 'Micorosoft.CSharp' could not be found when I changed my project settings to 3.5.  Is there an easy fix?

Comment: @phan Switch back to version you were working with or Install 3.5 framework. Second option has a much higher chance of making your problems worse.

Comment: @phan, looks like its still referencing .net 4.0 somewhere. Try modifying the language version(to 3.0) in Project properties->Build->Advanced

Comment: @appcoder In the Build tab, I see no advanced option.  Up top is a Configuration dropdown menu, and a Platform dropdown menu.

Comment: @Phan, you might need to scroll the Build tab view down to see the "Advanced" button in the lower right part of the configuration view (yes, it's a scrollable configuration view).